# Is this a fair bulkification of getContentasPDF?

Tags: callout, bulkification

I have to bulkify a handler which utilizes `getContentasPDF` method. Initially I was passing only single record id in the future method. Now I am passing `set<Id>` as parameter in `savePDF` which is a future method inside this handler class

```
public class PDFCreation {

        @future(callout=true)
            public static void savePDF(set<Id> reportIdset){

                Integer day_d1;
                Integer month_d1;
                Integer year_d1;
                Integer day_d2;
                Integer month_d2;
                Integer year_d2;

                Map<Id, Expense_Report__c> expMap = new Map<Id,Expense_report__c>([select createdBy.name, Period_Start_Date__c, Period_End_Date__c from expense_report__c where id =:reportIdset]);

                Map<Id, blob> blobMap = new Map<Id, blob>();

            for(id reportId:reportIdset){
                blob body;
                pageReference pageref = page.ExpensePDF;
                pageRef.getParameters().put('q',reportId);

                try
                   {
                     body = pageref.getContentAsPDF();
                     blobMap.put(reportId, body);
                   }

                catch(calloutException ce)
                  {
                      ExceptionLogging.addException('ExpenseReportPDF',ce);
                  }
            }         

                  list<attachment> attlist = new list<attachment>();

               for(id reportId:reportIdset){   

                  Attachment pdfatt = new Attachment();

                  pdfatt.parentid = reportId;
                  pdfatt.body = blobMap.get(reportId);
                  pdfatt.name = 'BennieandtheJets';
                  attlist.add(pdfatt);
                 } 

              try
                 {
                  insert attlist;
                 }

              catch(DMLexception de){
                  ExceptionLogging.addException('ExpenseReportPDFCreation',de);
                  }

            }

            private void saveExceptionLog(){
            ExceptionLogging.saveException();
            }

}
```

Is calling `getContentasPDF` inside the for loop as in below snippet appropriate?

```
for(id reportId:reportIdset){
                    blob body;
                    pageReference pageref = page.ExpensePDF;
                    pageRef.getParameters().put('q',reportId);

                    try
                       {
                         body = pageref.getContentAsPDF();
                         blobMap.put(reportId, body);
                       }
}
```

My question is around callouts limits as

> "getContentAsPDF() Methods is now Treated as Callout”

Are there any design patterns for callouts ?

Comment: Here is one design pattern for callouts - Appleman's Advanced Apex 3rd Edition Chapter 7 - Async Apex.  Uses queueables and is very scalable.  The example he uses in the book is a callout to Google Translate

Comment: @crop1645 Hi Eric, is there any specific reason that you suggest Queueable over Batch apex?

Comment: The reason for the pattern is that it works for all async use cases - future, batch, schedulable and thus provides a certain elegance so code doesn't always need to be reinvented. Queueable also runs faster than batches.  Read the book and decide for yourself.  I offered the comment as a suggestion to consider, nothing more

Comment: @kibitzer why your `GoingAsync3` is a `without sharing` class ?

Comment: I believe the answer is so that the user that inserts an `AsyncRequest__c` will get a queueable job that runs in the same privileges (and hence respects the requester's sharing rules).  This was covered in Chapter 7

Comment: @crop1645 Ahhh, I see. I read until Queueable class. Should finish reading the whole chapter. Thanks Eric!